# Docusign API generated envelope is not following routing order

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I generate a mixed ceremony envelope using a composite template:

```
{
"status": "sent",
"emailBlurb": "testing creation from template",
"emailSubject": "Please sign this template",
"compositeTemplates": [{
        "serverTemplates": [{
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "3f35423e-884a-4bf2-a9b5-19eaac4a5b8f"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [{
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "inPersonSigners": [{
                            "name": "LLLLL",
                            "email": "LLLL@some.com",
                            "hostemail": "LLLLL@some.com",
                            "hostname": "LLLLLL",
                            "roleName": "Signer 1",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "clientUserId": "1000",
                            "signerName": "John Signer",
                            "signerEmail": "jsigner@ds.com",
                            "requireIdLookUp": "true",
                            "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
                            "smsAuthentication": {
                                "senderProvidedNumbers": ["+34676363577"]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "signers": [{
                            "name": "VVVVVVV",
                            "email": "v@onecompany.com",
                            "roleName": "Signer 2",
                            "clientUserId": "2000",
                            "routingOrder": "2",
                            "recipientId": "2"
                        }, {
                            "name": "ZZZZZ",
                            "email": "z@onecompany.com",
                            "roleName": "Signer 3",
                            "clientUserId": "3000",
                            "routingOrder": "3",
                            "recipientId": "3"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "customFields": {
                    "textCustomFields": [{
                            "value": "8009E0000006Qu5QAJ",
                            "required": "false",
                            "show": "false",
                            "name": "##SFContract"
                        }
                    ]
                },
            }
        ]
    }
],
"eventNotification": {
    "RecipientEvents": [{
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed"
        }, {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "sent"
        }, {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "delivered"
        }, {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "declined"
        }
    ],
    "EnvelopeEvents": [{
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Delivered"
        }, {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed"
        }, {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent"
        }, {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

The template has an In Person Signer as the first signer (routing order 1) and two e-mail signers as second signers (routing order 2)

If I start this process from the template itself or from salesforce, when the in person signing ceremony is finished, it sends the e-mails for the other two signers to complete, but this doesn't happen if the signing url is taken from this envelope. If I check the document status in Docusign, it's waiting for the second and third signatures.

I need to have SMS Auth (thus the composite template and API generation) and an in person signer with two e-mail signers.

Am I missing something in my envelope generation for the process to continue?

Thanks!

Comment: `If I start this process from the template itself or from salesforce` Which process are you refering to?

Comment: `but this doesn't happen if the signing url is taken from this envelope` Can you explain this.. How are you taking the Signing Url from the envelope?

Comment: If I generate the envelope via API I get this behaviour but if I generate it from Salesforce (via Docusign for salesforce) I don't get SMS Auth but I get the expected behaviour with the flow continuing after the inPerson Signer

Comment: `If I generate the envelope via API I get this behaviour` What do you mean by this behaviour?

Comment: `I don't get SMS Auth but I get the expected behaviour`.. What behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: After the inPerson Signer finishes signing e-mails should be sent to the e-mail signers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For emails to be sent remove the `clientUserId` parameter from the Signers. This parameter indicates the signer is an [embedded signer](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSigning).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything special you'd need to do to trigger the sending of the signature request email to subsequent signers in the workflow -- when one recipient finishes (i.e., submits a completed envelope), DocuSign should automatically advance to the next recipient in the workflow (where "next" recipient is determined by **routingOrder**), and send the signature request email(s).

If you're getting different behaviors in the 2 scenarios that you've described, I'd suggest that you troubleshoot by issuing a [GET Envelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/get/) request (`GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}`) after the first (in-person) signer finishes in each scenario, then carefully comparing the API response from scenario 1 to the API response from scenario 2. If DocuSign is behaving differently in scenario 1 compared to scenario 2, then there must be some difference in the Envelope structure (specifically, with the issue that you're describing, in the properties that are set for the Recipients (signers) in the Envelope).

BTW - have you tried specifying **routingOrder=1** for the **inPersonSigner** recipient?  (I'm not seeing a **routingOrder** property for that recipient in the JSON that you've posted.)

Comment: Just tried adding the routingOrder to the inPersonSigner and didn't get a different outcome. I'll try issuing the GET request in both cases and look for any differences